# What is the flow of a request to a server with a queue in the middle?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm trying very hard to understand the flow of a web request to a server which has a queue or message broker in the middle, but I can't find information about when and where the reply is given.

Imagine this use case:

Client A:

1. sends a invoice order request
2. the invoice is enqueued
3. the request is processed and dequeued.

at which time the client will receive a response?
right after the message is received by the queue?
right after the message is processed and dequeued? Other?

I'm asking because if the reply only comes after the message being processed the client might wait a long time. Imagine the message takes 3 minutes to process, would the client need to keep requesting the server to see if it is processed? or a connection is maintained using something like long polling?

I'm interested in scenarios using RabbitMq and kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of having a messaging system is to ensure the frontend webserver and backend processing is decoupled. Best practice is Web server should publish the message and just wait for the messaging system to acknowledge receiving the message.

Comment: I think you are not replying to my question, please read again :)